[PyTelegramBotAPI]Error Sending Media Group with Video and Thumbnail: BufferedReader is Not JSON Serializable
I'm encountering an issue using PyTelegramBotApi that's driving me crazy. I want to send a media group message from my bot to a channel. The media group contains a single video with a custom thumbnail.
Here’s the relevant part of my code:
watermarked_video_path = f"/data/watermarked_{video.video.file_id}.mp4"
thumbnail_path = "/data/thumbnail.jpg"
test = telebot.types.InputMediaVideo(open(watermarked_video_path, 'rb'), thumbnail=open(thumbnail_path, 'rb'))
self.bot.send_media_group(chat_id, [test])

The last line of the code (send_media_group) fails with the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/TGbot.py", line 141, in process_and_forward_media
    self.bot.send_media_group(chat_id, [test])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/telebot/__init__.py", line 3355, in send_media_group
    result = apihelper.send_media_group(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/telebot/apihelper.py", line 579, in send_media_group
    media_json, files = convert_input_media_array(media)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/telebot/apihelper.py", line 2225, in convert_input_media_array
    return json.dumps(media), files
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/json/__init__.py", line 231, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/json/encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/json/encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/json/encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type BufferedReader is not JSON serializable
2024-12-05 14:48:22,254 - ERROR - Error processing and forwarding the media: Object of type BufferedReader is not JSON serializable

Without any thumbnail code works as expected. The thumbnail is a valid JPEG file. As per the official Telegram documentation:

Its longest side does not exceed 320px.
Its file size is under 200KB.

Code is running inside Python 3.9 oficial Docker Image.
Am I missing something in how I'm constructing the InputMediaVideo object or the send_media_group call? Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!
